# How to render string html

Tags: twig, drupal-9

I have custom block which has following code.

```
 foreach ($video_result as $video){
    $title = $video->title;
    $video_body = $video->body_value; 
  }
  
 var_dump($video_body);

    $renderable = [
        '#theme' => 'video-block',
        '#title' => $title,
        '#description' => $video_body
      ];
      return $renderable;
```

And this return to twig file such as

```
<h6>Title {{ title }}</h6>
{{ description | raw}}
```

I get output as html on browser and when i inspect it i see html is wrap with double quotes. I have to render it as video on browser. What i am doing wrong here

Comment: Why are you applying `htmlentities` to the variable `$video`? This will convert all HTML to HTML entities, e.g. `<div>` becomes `&lt;div&gt;`

Comment: Then please suggest me the right way to achieve my requirements.

Comment: Don't apply `htmlentities`?

Comment: I have this value which i have to pass to twig file to render the video . How i pass that so that i get the value and render in twig file so that video start displaying on browser.

Comment: <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/VideoObject"><meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="Fri Jan 21 2022 15:15:46 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)"/><meta itemprop="name" content="Laredo Economic Development"/><meta itemprop="duration" content="P0Y0M0DT0H2M59S" /><meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/thumbs/vbnSJqwQ-720.jpg"/><meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/vbnSJqwQ-ja6y4YQJ.m4a"/><script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/players/vbnSJqwQ-ND0v4fqv.js"></script></div>

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($video)`?

Comment: If i remove htmlentities $video is printing empty div `<div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/VideoObject"></div>` . I want whole video player code but it just printing empty div. var_dump is showing me string(541).

Comment: Add the output of the var_dump as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71433680/edit) in your question

Comment: Done. If i do var_dump($video_body) . Then on browser video start playing and also getting string(541) before  video " video playing on browser  " and quotes end after video.

Comment: At this point I can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/mlhs0a) this. Please update the code with how you actually are passing the variable from the controller to twig. The code above just shows that you return an array, also you suddenly changed `video` to `video_body`. If you are passing the exact array shown in the code then the variable `description` shouldn't even exist.

Answer (score -2):

Try Something Like This

{!! $description !!}

Comment: This does not solve OP's question at all, OP is using `twig`. Not even sure what framework the syntax above is from

Comment: Not work . Throws an error.

Comment: I am using twig template (symphony) . Passing variable from php file to twig file to render html.

Comment: But it render only this part  <div itemscope itemtype="schema.org/VideoObject"></div>.

Comment: you can use **template_from_string** function loads a template from a string.